# Python, Pandas: The Merged Sum of Some Rows according to Column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame example. I try to to have sum of some spesific rows. I have researched how to carry out, however I could not find the solution. Could you give a direction, please?  The example is as below. I thought that I can apply group by and sum but there is column (Value_3) that I would not like to sum of these, just keeping same. Value 3 is constant value, shaped due to Machine and Shift value.

```
data = {'Machine':['Mch_1', 'Mch_1', 'Mch_1', 'Mch_1', 'Mch_2', 'Mch_2'], 'Shift':['Day', 'Day', 'Night', 'Night', 'Night', 'Night'], 'Value_1':[1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3], 'Value_2':[0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0], 'Value_3':[5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 6]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output:

Mch_1__Day__1__0__5

Mch_1__Day__2__2__5

Mch_1__Night_0__2__2

Mch_1__Night_0__1__2

Mch_2__Night_1__3__6

Mch_2__Night_3__0__6

What I would like to have is like as showed in dataframe.

```
expected = {'Machine':['Mch_1', 'Mch_1', 'Mch_2'], 'Shift':['Day', 'Night', 'Night'], 'Value_1':[3, 0, 4], 'Value_2':[2, 3, 3]} 
df_expected = pd.DataFrame(expected) 
df_expected
```

Output:

Mch_1__Day__3__2__5

Mch_1__Night_0__3__2

Mch_2__Night_4__3__6

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea is pass dictionary for aggregate functions, for last column is possible use `first` or `last` function:

```
d = {'Value_1':'sum','Value_2':'sum','Value_3':'first'}
df1 = df.groupby(['Machine','Shift'], as_index=False).agg(d)
```

If want more dynamic solution it means sum all columns without `Value_3` create dyctionary by all columns without specified in list with `dict.from_keys` and [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['Machine','Shift', 'Value_3']), 'sum')
d['Value_3'] = 'first'
df1 = df.groupby(['Machine','Shift'], as_index=False).agg(d)
print (df1)
  Machine  Shift  Value_1  Value_2  Value_3
0   Mch_1    Day        3        2        5
1   Mch_1  Night        0        3        2
2   Mch_2  Night        4        3        6
```